# vokoscreenNG won't start, says "No videocodec found"

Tags: package-management, codecs

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Now when I open vokoscreenNG, I see this message:

> **No videocodec found**
>
> Please install package
>
> gstreatmer-plugins-base
> gstreatmer-plugins-good
> gstreatmer-plugins-bad
> gstreatmer-plugins-ugly
> gstreatmer-plugins-libav

[No videocodec found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B05KD.png)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Update:

Those packages are already installed. I uninstalled vokoscreenNG 3.4 and installed vokoscreenNG 3.1.0. Now I don't see the message above but I cannot choose mp4 format because no videocodecs are listed and when I choose any other format (mkv, webm, avi, mov), Vokoscreen will record the video but won't play back the file - it shows this message:

> To play this video a codec is needed. Please install a codec pack.

But all codecs are installed and I can play the videos in VLC player.

It's as though Vokoscreen is looking in the wrong location for the codecs.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: A good start is to install the packages it is asking for.

Comment: gstreamer (gst-launch-1.0) and it's requested packages are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same difficulty and discovered you can install the required codecs with the following commands:

Open a terminal window.
Required package is in the multiverse repo so :

`sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`

Next, you'll run update:

`sudo apt update`

Finally, install the codecs from the restricted extras:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

You will be warned about the repo

[image: end user license agreement]

Tab to the  button and press

[image: select yes on EULA]

You'll have to accept with the  button.

Everything will install and you'll have the codecs and VokoScreen will run properly.

You can install the correct codecs